# Can the Shaliach Tzibbur rely on the Amidah repetition to recover from something he forgot to say?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader

If someone frogot to recite *ya'aleh Veyavo* during Rosh Hodesh Shacharit, and he has finished the Amidah, he would need to repeat the whole Amidah.

Let's say the chazan forgot this during his silent Amidah. Can, he rely on the fact that he will say it during the aloud Amidah? Or, would he have to repeat the silent one, again?

What, if, for example, he realizes that he forgot to say this just before finishing his own silent Amidah. Someone who is not chazan, would return to Ya'aleh Veyavo and repeat from that point forward. Should that chazan be doing this, too? If so, why is that not considered *tircha detzibbur* ("burdening the congregation")?

Comment: Repeating an extra two blessings isn't such a burden

Comment: if he is able to fixe it while he is still in the middle of his amidah he can. if he already finished there is no need to repeat his personal one again